# How to get comments facebook from a url?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I using facebook comments for a url (ex: http://test.com/check.html)

I using `https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://test.com/check.html`

And result can't show comments from this url, How to show it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://test.com/check.html

Hope can help you !!!

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to access? For groups it is much more difficult. In general, however, you need what I describe below:

I'm not sure if you have this information, but you need to have the access token in the url. That is, your URL should look something like this: `'https://graph.facebook.com/[pageidhere]/feed?access_token=[access token here]'`
After that, you need to use json_decode($FBPageContent) to easily traverse the data.

An example I made using the above information (as well as a lot more stuff) is here: http://www.johnalibet.com/fb.php

I'll refine this answer as best I can if you can provide more information.